# Saving an item in a collection in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm not understanding how to properly bind a single item from a collection. In my project, a student can have multiple plans with these models:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        Plans = new HashSet<Plan>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Designee { get; set; }
    public string DesigneePhone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
}

public partial class Plan
{
    public int PlanId { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

I'm listing each plan with its own Save button on the page. I thought I was using the asp-for helper correctly according to [this Learn Razor Pages post](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections).

```
@page "{studentId:int}"
@model CollectionTest.PlansModel

<form asp-page-handler="SaveMain" method="post">
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Student.StudentId" />
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Student.Designee"></label>
            <input asp-for="Student.Designee" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <label asp-for="Student.DesigneePhone"></label>
            <input asp-for="Student.DesigneePhone" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto align-self-end">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<hr />

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Student.Plans.Count(); i++)
{
    var planId = Model.Student.Plans.ToList()[i].PlanId.ToString();

    <div id="@("card_Plan" + planId)" class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5>Plan #@planId</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="@("form_Plan" + planId)" asp-page-handler="SavePlan" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].PlanId" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="@("form_Plan" + planId)">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But it seems like nothing is being bound in the SavePlan page handler:

```
[BindProperty]
public Student Student { get; set; }
.
.
.
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSavePlan(int planId)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    /******************************
     *
     * Student.Plans is empty and planId is zero
     *
     *******************************/
    Plan plan = await _planContext.Plan.FirstAsync(p => p.PlanId == planId);

    _planContext.Attach(plan).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await _planContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!PlanExists(plan.PlanId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./Plans");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code, because what you pass in the razor page is `[0].PlanId`, but what you receive in the OnPostSavePlan method is `planId`. If you only need to receive `planId`, you need to change the form.

```
<div class="card-body">
        <form id="@("form_Plan" + planId)" asp-page-handler="SavePlan" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@planId" />
```

From your requirement,it seems you want to pass a list of plans. So you need to modify your code in the following steps:

Plans.cshtml:

```
<form id="form_Plan" asp-page-handler="SavePlan" method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Student.Plans.Count(); i++)
    {
        var planId = Model.Student.Plans.ToList()[i].PlanId.ToString();

        <div id="@("card_Plan" + planId)" class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5>Plan #@planId</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].PlanId" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].StartDate"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Student.Plans.ToList()[i].EndDate"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    <div class="card-footer">
        <div class="float-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="form_Plan">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Plans.cshtml.cs:

```
public class PlansModel : PageModel
{
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        //for easy testing,I add the data manually
        Student = new Student()
        {
            Plans = new List<Plan>()
            {
                new Plan(){  PlanId=1, StartDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-8-7")},
                new Plan(){  PlanId=2, StartDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-4-7")},
                new Plan(){  PlanId=3, StartDate=DateTime.Parse("2019-6-7")}
            }
        };
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSavePlan(List<Plan> plans)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

Plans.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var plan in Model.Student.Plans)
{
    var planId = plan.PlanId.ToString();
    <div id="@("card_Plan" + planId)" class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h5>Plan #@planId</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="@("form_Plan" + planId)" asp-page-handler="SavePlan" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@plan.PlanId" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="@plan.StartDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="@plan.StartDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@plan.StartDate"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="@plan.EndDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="@plan.EndDate" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="@plan.EndDate"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="float-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="@("form_Plan" + planId)">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Plans.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSavePlan(Plan plan)
{
    //...
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried your code and it works, however I'd like a Save button for each plan (requirements for this project). I used my original code and updated my page handler to `OnPostSavePlan(Plan plan)` but `plan.PlanId` is still 0 and the other properties are `null` (except `StudentId'). What am I still missing?

Comment: Thanks, Rena, it's working for me now. Quick follow-up question: if I need the value of `plan.StudentId` in my handler I need to add `<input type="hidden" asp-for="@plan.StudentId" />`, correct? And the same thing for any other property I need in the page handler?

Comment: I also noticed that Chrome DevTools is giving me lots of "Found X elements with non-unique id" warnings. I think that's why I started using the index in the `asp-for` to begin with.

Comment: Yes.If you need the value of `plan.StudentiId`,you need a hidden field to pass it to the handler.The handler just keep same.

Comment: If my answer helped you,could accept as answer.And it would also help others who has similar issue.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to fix the problem of having multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: emm...You need to know that model binding is not related to the id,it depends on the name.Not sure what is your razor pages and backend data you want receive.I suggest that you could post a new thread and give a sample.It would be more helpful.

Comment: I'm talking about _your_ code. If there are ten plans, then the `asp-for="plan.StartDate"` you have will create ten inputs with `id="plan_StartDate" name="plan.StartDate"`.

Comment: So you do not want to make them with same id?Why?If so,just avoid using `asp-for` and use name property.